# Zooming WPF canvas relative to the center rather than top left

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scaletransform

I am writing a label-making program. In this program, I have a canvas with a white rectangle positioned in the center, with multiple objects that the user can resize, drag, etc on top of it. I also have an option for the user to zoom the canvas, which I accomplish using `ScaleTransform` via `LayoutTransform`. I want to have it so that, when the user zooms in, the canvas zooms in on the center, rather than relative to the top right.

Here's a demonstration:

Currently, the canvas zooms like this:

[image]

I need it to zoom like this:

[image]

How can I accomplish this task, without re-positioning the elements in the canvas when it is zoomed?

**Note**: I'm using LayoutTransform, since I must embed this in a `ScrollViewer`. `RenderTransform` accomplishes this, but won't let the user scroll when canvas elements exceed the visible canvas bounds.

Comment: Have you tried setting `RenderTransformOrigin` (for your Canvas) to `0.5,0.5`? (of course this means `RenderTransform` is used for your Canvas, not `LayoutTransform`).

Comment: @KingKing I'm using LayoutTransform, since I must embed this in a `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: see it this helps [How to auto center the content in a scrollviewer while zooming](http://xaml.in/xaml/how-to-auto-center-the-content-in-a-scrollviewer-while-zooming)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Border>
                <Border.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2.0" ScaleY="2.0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.LayoutTransform>
                <Canvas Background="Red" Width="500" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-100"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Yellow"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Border>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to accomplish the same thing as RenderTransformOrigin, by using a transform that combines two translations around the scaling. E.g. using TransformGroup, or combining matrices for a MatrixTransform.

Specifically: translate the center point (X,Y) to (0,0) by using translation offsets of -X and -Y, perform the scale transform, and then translate (0,0) back to the original point (X, Y) using translation offsets of X and Y.

It's hard for me to know for sure without having a specific code example, but I have a vague sense that it ought to be possible to use RenderTransform, perhaps applied differently than you'd prefer (e.g. adding a new container to the hierarchy and applying it to that). But assuming RenderTransform simply won't work, the above should.

Comment: Could you be more specific when you say 'translate the center point?'

Comment: Sorry for my vagueness. What I mean is to create a transform that will translate the center point to the desired location. Of course, such a transform will also translate all other points...it's just that thinking in terms of the specific point makes it clear what the transform should be (or at least, should make it clear :) ): a TranslateTransform is just an X and Y offset, so to translate a given point (X1,Y1) to (0,0), you simply define a transform where the X and Y offsets are -X1 and -Y1 respectively. Then all points are shifted by that amount, with the point (X1, Y1) moved to (0,0)